# how to make a "help" screen thst ovlays a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I trying to make a help screen to overlay my fragment.
I need a half transparent screen with a full transparent circle that shows what the user needs to do.

i didn't add any code because i don't have any idea how to start.

any help?

Thanks,
Ilan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this library: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

> ShowcaseView is a library which helps give your app that extra flair. It is designed to easily insert reliable, Holo-designed guides into your app, to point out features that users might not notice, such as gestures.